# Function Calling Error While linking on WSL

Tags: c++, linux, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gn

I have a project which is being developed in C++. The Build Files are getting created using GN along with Clang. But the issue is that I am not able to create the executable main from GN. You can see the functions defined below for reference.

Add.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "add.h"
#include<iostream>
void A::add1(int a,int b)
{
    std::cout<<"The value of A is "<<a<<" and the value of B is"<<b<<" and thier sum is"<<a+b<<std::endl;
}
```

Sub.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "sub.h"
#include<iostream>
void check::sub1(int a,int b)
{
    std::cout<<"A-B is "<<a-b<<std::endl;
}
```

and similarly, Multiply Function And Division Function.

The pch function is defined as :-

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H
#define BUILDING_DLL_LIB 

#include "framework.h"

#endif
```

FrameWork Function:-

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) // Microsoft compiler
    #include <windows.h>
#elif defined(__GNUC__) // GNU compiler
    #include <dlfcn.h>

#endif
```

Main:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include "../add/SampleDll.h"
#include "../add/add.h"
#include "../sub/sub.h"
#include "../mul/mul.h"
#include "../div/div.h"
int main()
{
    CSampleDll obj;
    A obj1;
    check obj2;
    C obj3;
    D obj4;
    obj1.add1(10,5);
    obj2.sub1(10,5);
    obj3.mul1(10,5);
    obj4.div1(10,5);
}
```

But the issue is while Building File using gn, I am getting this error for linux:-

```
clang++ -pthread -rdynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath-link= -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--strip-discarded -Wl,--gc-sections -m64 -o ./main @main.rsp
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main/main.o: in function `main':
/mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `CSampleDll::CSampleDll()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `A::add1(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `check::sub1(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `C::mul1(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `D::div1(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `CSampleDll::~CSampleDll()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `CSampleDll::~CSampleDll()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The Shared libraries are getting created properly for each function but while linking, I am getting the above error. The command executed for main is :-

```
clang++ -g -Wl,/debug -Wl,/ignore:4099 -Wl,/dynamicbase -Wl,/subsystem:console -Wl,/nxcompat -Wl,/safeseh:no -Wl,/nodefaultlib:libcmt.lib -Wl,/incremental -Wl,/machine:x64 -m64 -o ./main.exe @main.exe.rsp ./add.lib ./sub.lib ./mul.lib ./div.lib -lmsvcrt.lib -lgdi32.lib -lshell32.lib -ladvapi32.lib -ldelayimp.lib -lBcrypt.lib -loldnames.lib
```

Also, I tried to set up path using `LIBRARY_PATH` in Window Subsytem for linux (WSL) using :-

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/path/to/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH
```

When, the above `LIBRARY_PATH` didn't worked, I tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using:-

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/path/to/lib::$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/path/to/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Nothing is working for WSL and I am confused where I am wrong. Please, any help will be highly appreciated.

**P.S.- The Above project is working on windows.**

Answer (score 0):

we are missing some clue information.

But it look like you have an issue in linking the lib, if you got sometimes to spare you may want to try to make a MakeFile to compile all of that code.
Or start making a CMake to clarify things.

Most of the time compilation is different between windows and linux, you may want to search if you don't use any windows based commands.

And lastly WLS can be somewhat capricious, if you think it's not your code and compilation, I recommend you to try either in a virtual machine, or in dual boot